# When installing the software that was developed using NSIS, how should I throw a pop-up message if installing in server operating systems

Tags: nsis

When installing the software that was developed using NSIS, how should I throw a pop-up message if installing in server operating systems.

Below are the unsupported operating systems. In those when installing the software i should show the popup message.

```
Windows Server 2003 
Windows Server 2003 R2
Windows Server 2008
Windows Server 2008 R2 
Windows Server 2012 
Windows Server 2012 R2
```

I am facing difficulty to implement this. Could any one please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WinVer.nsh` to detect Windows versions

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"    
!include "WinVer.nsh"

Function .onInit
    ${If} ${IsServerOS}
        MessageBox MB_OK "Running on Windows Server."
        Quit
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

If you need to be more specific, you can combine this with at `AtLeastWin*` / `AtMostWin*`, where `*` is the version you're targeting (e.g. [`AtLeastWin2003`](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Includes/WinVer/AtLeastWin2003.md) / [`AtLeastWin2012R2`](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Includes/WinVer/AtLeastWin2012R2.md))

Comment: Thank you for the solution. While installing, in .OnInit function can I use like as shown below and Quit if it is the windows server operating system?           
 !include "WinVer"
Function .onInit
${If} ${IsServerOS}
MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONQUESTION "You are attempting to install software that is not intended for this version of windows OS"
Quit
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Answer (score 0):

Use `WinVer.nsh` to detect Windows versions:

```
!include WinVer.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!define /IfNDef ERROR_INSTALL_REJECTED 1654

Function .onInit
${If} ${IsServerOS}
    ${If} ${AtLeastWin2003}
    ${AndIf} ${AtMostWin2012R2}
        MessageBox mb_IconStop|mb_OK "Not allowed to run on this version of Windows for some reason!" /SD IDOK
        SetErrorLevel ${ERROR_INSTALL_REJECTED}
        Quit
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Keep in mind that this does not block the server versions of NT4 and 2000 nor Server 2016. You only need the `${IsServerOS}` check if you want to block all server versions.